# Having trouble understanding why my app crashes

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm trying to upload an image to the Firebase storage. This is what I have so far:

```
fileprivate func uploadImageToFirebase(){
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    guard let uploadData = imageToUpload?.pngData() else { return }
    storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        print(metadata)
    }
}
```

uploadData is not nil, but my app crashes. this is what I get:

```
reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
```

I tried to look up, but couldn't understand why the app crash and how to fix it.
I got it that I'm trying to insert a nil, but I don't have anything nil.

Comment: You need to do some troubleshooting. Add a breakpoint in your code and step through it one line at a time. During that, examine your variables to determine which one is not what you expect. It's also a good idea to tell us which line crashes. Also, why aren't you checking to see if metadata is nil as shown in the [Upload Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory) documentation?

Comment: I did put a breakpoint, forgot to mention though. It crashes on storageRef.putData. It does not seems to be null, but just crashes right after that. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, this is what I have now:

```
fileprivate func uploadImageToFirebase(completion: @escaping((_ url: String?)->())){
    let imageName = UUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    let imagesRef = storageRef.child(imageName)
    guard let uploadData = imageToUpload?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) else { return }

    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    imagesRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: metaData) { (metadata, err) in
        if err == nil && metadata != nil {
            imagesRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, err) in
                guard let downloadUrl = url else { return } 
                let urlString = downloadUrl.absoluteString
                completion(urlString)
            })
        }
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The problem with the code in the question was there was no name assigned to the file to upload. In other words

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
```

is a reference to the storage itself, but when uploading to storage there needs to be a filename like this

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
let myFile = storageRef.child("my_cool_pic.jpg")
```

and the use is

```
myFile.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil)...
```

Comment: I imagine you got a downvote because there's no explanation with the code so readers can understand what the issue was. Best practice here on SO is to add a brief explanation as to what the code does, Code Only answer are discouraged. I added an EDIT to your answer and tossed you an upvote. It took me a few minutes to see the problem as well - Good job finding the issue!

Comment: @Jay Thank you very much! I did forgot to add an explanation, will remember it for now on. Thank you very much again!